# Why one miner can dig out many blocks continually in one moment?

Tags: blockchain, security, majority-attack, cpuminer

I am new to bitcoin and blockchain, I browed the [website](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/blocks?page=1) just now. There is  a question confusing me,  I find that one miner dig out blocks many times even in one hour. For example, this [miner](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY) dig out four block in 6:00 - 7:00 AM. Is it possible that this miner control 51% CPU? And may this would break the whole bitcoin blockchain?

I hope someone can answer me, thanks！

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it just a succession of lucky event, even if this miner wanted to do a 51% attack, [there is not a lot he could have done with it](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-can-an-attacker-with-51-of-hash-power-do), except as you said break or reduce the trust in the bitcoin network, and someone who have invest that much money into mining equipment must own and will own lots of bitcoin and so have less incentive to try to break it.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I have another question. Some transaction have multi inputs, like [this transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/9a53cddca1e219f7917ce1475e7bda75c784756d03f6ef4eaa08ca7c3a17e6cd), In my view, one transaction may have many output,but only one input. And I begin to know a concept **UTXO** .  if `A -> B`, `C -> D` some btc， and `B,D -> E, F` . Does this mean that two people B and D give some btc to E and F  simultaneously?  or  there is  one man B or D to initiate this transaction.  Thank you again!

Comment: [This transaction](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/43105e5686ca15a0e34463ed399c2a20bd89ed909b1657377c5fed5dd6376e51), there are many input, and takes the change of 124.98. Is it possible to use fewer input and less change？for example reduce 9 input and the change is less than 12.5 btc.

Comment: @Issem You should check the answer of this question https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43134/how-would-you-end-up-with-more-than-two-transaction-outputs